# How do I download Calibre on Ubuntu?

Tags: drm, calibre

I know nothing about code. I'd need a blow-by-blow, subtle as an atomic bomb explanation of how to download Calibre on Linux, with Ubuntu.

Comment: We don't know what Ubuntu product, or release you're using, but I see the package available, ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=calibre  where a simple `sudo apt install calibre` will install the package for the releases listed in the page. You'll note it comes from `universe` thus that will need to be enabled, but you gave no product/release details so we can't know if that applies to you already  (refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu or questions on this site on enabling *universe* if necessary for your unstated system).

Answer (score 4):

Calibre does not recommend using the versions supplied in your linux distro.

Instead go to the terminal and issue the following command.

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```

Be prepared to type in your password when the **sudo** programs asks for it and press enter. Calibre is a complex piece of software, but it's excellent at detecting dependencies in your environment and downloading then symlinking the packages to use.

When done, just type **calibre** to start up this program. I've been using it for years and find it's an excellent way to manage both personal and professional files I've collected over time. Its built-in reader for epub is usually pretty good.

Comment: Yep, right from their site it states it:  "Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described below."  This is the correct answer here.  +1

Answer (score 1):

It's in the ubuntu software center.  Open the orange icon in the upper left and search for calibre.

Comment: The version in the software center is always out of date (although right now it's not too far off, only about 10 versions out of date).   It's better to download from the author.